# Indy 10 HTTPS Proxy

Tags: http, delphi, https, proxy, indy

I have a small program here that uses idHTTP to download some things from a https server . I need to alter this program to use a HTTPS Proxy server . 
I got two IP addresses for the proxy 1.1.1.1 8080 for HTTP , and 2.2.2.2 8084 for HTTPS .

I altered my code to look like this :

```
  try
   IdHTTP1:=TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
   try
    LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    try
      // does not seem to do anything
      LHandler.TransparentProxy.Host:='2.2.2.2';
      LHandler.TransparentProxy.Port:=8084;
      LHandler.TransparentProxy.Enabled:=true;

      // this works even when using HTTP proxy for HTTPS
      idHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyServer:='1.1.1.1';
      idHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyPort:=8080;


      IdHTTP1.IOHandler:=LHandler;
      Src:= IdHTTP1.Get('https://csv.business.tomtom.com/extern?account='+company+'&username='+user+'&password='+password+'&apikey='+apikey+'&lang=en&action=showObjectReportExtern');
    finally
      LHandler.Free;
    end;
   finally
     IdHTTP1.Free;
   end;
  except on E: Exception do
//      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
```

Can someone please show me how do I tell idHTTP LHandler to USE the HTTPS Proxy ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use ONLY the `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams` by itself, and be sure to assign it the *correct* HTTP proxy to use for the protocol scheme you are requesting (HTTP vs HTTPS):

```
try
  IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP1);
    IdHTTP1.IOHandler := LHandler;

    IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := '2.2.2.2';
    IdHTTP1.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 8084;

    Src := IdHTTP1.Get('https://csv.business.tomtom.com/extern?account='+company+'&username='+user+'&password='+password+'&apikey='+apikey+'&lang=en&action=showObjectReportExtern');
  finally
    IdHTTP1.Free;
  end;
except
  on E: Exception do
    // Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
end;
```

The `TransparentProxy` property does not work the way you think it does.

When you do not explicitly assign a `TIdCustomTransparentProxy`-derived component to the `TransparentProxy` property (which you are not), the property getter creates a default `TIdSocksInfo` component.  You do not want to use a SOCKS proxy in this situation, and besides, the `TIdCustomTransparentProxy.Enabled` property is the wrong way to enable a `TIdSocksInfo`, you have to use the `TIdSocksInfo.Version` property instead.

Comment: Thank you , very-very much . I googled and googled , and got really confused :) But now that I think about it . When I create this idHTTP I either use HTTP or HTTPS not both . So if I use HTTPS I use the HTTPS Proxy IP and Port .